# How to check in WiX, if user has admin rights?

Tags: wix

I have programmed a Bootstrapper application with WiX 3.8, which installs IIS Express 8.0 and activates IIS-features.
But the feature-activation only works, when the user is a local administrator at least.
How can i check in a WiX-Bootstrapper, if the user has admin rights?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

See:

[Burn Built-in Variables](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html)

> •Privileged - non-zero if the process could run elevated (on Vista+)
>   or is running as an Administrator (on WinXP).

This is similar to the Windows Installer [Privileged property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370852(v=vs.85).aspx).

Also check that you are using the PerMachine attribute on the ExePackage element if you are using it.